# JPA + CascadeType + cache

Tags: java, caching, jpa, cascade, relation

I have some issues with JPA cache, the scenario is as follows:

I had two classes A and B with relationship ManyToMany, but then i split the ManyToMany into two OneToMany relations and new class

```
public class A{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="a")
    private List<AB> ab;
}

public class B{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="b")
    private List<AB> ab;
}


public class AB{

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "A_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     private A a;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "B_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     private B b;

     ...other fields
}
```

My problem is that when i delete A: i want to A and AB to be deleted, and B not touched in db (the same if i delete B).

That works, and DB state is fine but there is problem with JPA and cache.
When i remove A (and AB with cascade), JPA cache still holds references to them in B instance - what is undesirable. So when i query for B i will find nested AB instances that were removed.

I tried to put cascades on AB ManyToMany fields but it doesn't help.
If i clear cache with : entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll(); everything works but it's not a good solution.

I use EntityManager with EJB3, and cascades from javax.persistence.

I would be grateful for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to [eclipselink 2 OneToMany with one association table how to delete from one side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804975/eclipselink-2-onetomany-with-one-association-table-how-to-delete-from-one-side)  . So, before deleting A (and therefore deleting AB), remove all references from B to AB.

Comment: So your'e saying that there is no way to do it with cascades or sth automatically ? I was expecting that it will be possible and i just don't know the solution or correct setup but if that's not the case i will have to handle references by myself what is not a good news for me.

Comment: @Rychu: How about using `getCache().evict(theClass, thePrimaryKey)` instead of `getCache().evictAll()`? It should evict individual objects of a given type from 2nd level cache.

Comment: Of course it's better to evict one class than all cache, but i wanted to avoid evict in general. I think i will have to manually remove references.